# Posting to most pages throws 404

Tags: 404-error

I have a problem with a Wordpress installation where POST requests to any page apart from a couple in the root fail with a 404.  POSTing to wp-atom.php succeeds, but POSTing to another custom page in the root fails with a 404.  Wordpress is processing the request as its the Wordpress 404 page that is being returned.

Is there some filter that could be intercepting the request and denying all but a few POST requests?

Comment: Have you read [Page returns 404 with POST variables, but not without](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77337/73)?

Comment: Thanks. That sort of helps - my page is actually the opposite - it works with POST variables, but returns 404 without.

Comment: Further to my last comment - could it be one or more of the reserved names are being used in the POST, causing it to fail?  This page was working correctly, but has to accept requests from an external source, which could have changed.

Comment: Yes, using reserved names can result in 404s. You have to follow each name until it triggers a 404 to solve this.

Comment: Thanks - I'll follow up with the source and see if I can get a complete list of what they are sending.