# Form submission to another page returning 404 error

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, forms, 404-error

I'm modifying a form plugin, and trying to have it submit to another page chosen by the user. Right now the page it submits to is `page_id=6`. If I navigate to this page myself, it prints `Array()`. When I submit the form, I get a 404 error although the url matches.

`page_id=6` uses the shortcode `[convertable]` to include this code:

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I'm testing in on a WPMU install. You can see the form [here](http://test.advancedadvertising.us/?page_id=4)

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: which plugin you are using for this purpose?

Comment: Have you seen this: [Page returns 404 with POST variables, but not without](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77337/page-returns-404-with-post-variables-but-not-without/77339#77339)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `name='name'` for your first input.  That breaks it.  Change the name to something else as suggested above, prefix everything.  `name='my-prefix-name'`

Comment: totally spaced it on the whole reserved variable thing. Thanks a lot for your help on that. I'll have to add a check to the plugin to make sure the user doesn't set 'Name' as one of the form fields, and also pass this on to the plugins original creator.