# Calling custom PHP from a HTML form post action gives 404 error

Tags: forms

I have a form:

```
<form name="customer_details" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()"
    action="../customer-details.php">
```

I placed the PHP file in my theme folder, but WordPress gives me an error:

> 404 — Fancy meeting you here!

Comment: You have provided no code, link, or any specific information to make any help possible.

Comment: See also: [Page returns 404 with POST variables, but not without](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77337/73)

Answer (score 0):

You can just define an action method in function file and leave form action blank.

Use hook init by

```
add_action('init',formaction);
function formaction() {
    if($_post['submit']=='1') {
        //form submit code here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add unique field in your form.

```
Eg: <input type="hidden" name="wdm_action" value="1">
```

Put your `'customer-details.php'` file code in below function:-

```
 add_action('template_redirect','wdm_customer_details'){
//check if that field present in the form, if yes then perform the action
if(isset($_POST['wdm_action'] && $_POST['wdm_action'] != ''){
    //customer-details.php file code

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1 You need to change the form action and easiest way to do is creat a page with name like "x form action" (slug xaction). Now publish it and create a page template for this page like "page-xaction.php".

For know more about creating page template read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/).

## 2 Now change the form action like this:

```
<?php
echo esc_url(get_permalink(100));
?>
```

Please note 100 is the ID of the page you have created "x form action".

Now you are good to write your form action code in the file page-xaction.php

Also read about wp_nonce [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)

Answer (score 0):

You should change this (if you dont use that `php` file directly, like example.com/customer-details.php`):

```
action="../customer-details.php"
```

to

```
action=""
```

instead, you should use that as `page template`, then change to:

```
action="example.com/pagename"
```