# $POST variable is empty in receiving php add-on function but can be seen by jscript function

Tags: plugins, forms

I have created the following code to explain my problem.

Firstly I have a shortcode function which accepts a user input and calls another form:

```
<?php
add_shortcode('quote_system', 'qt_system');

function qt_system() {
    $postUrl = get_option('post-url');
    echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $postUrl);
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $postUrl); ?>" method="post" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username"/>     
    <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
<?php
}  ?>
```

Second If I set the variable $postUrl to a static page 'check.php' all is well and the $username shows on the screen:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $myuser = $_POST['username'];
    echo "The following was passed (".$myuser.")";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I use a shortcode version within another wordpress form, I just get the message 'The following was passed ()'.   The same code works on my test server but not on the production machine (1 & 1) which we have just started using.   It seems there is some sort of configuration issue but 1&1 are unable to help.   Does anyone have any idea what this might be.

Here is the receiving shortcode function:

```
<?php
add_shortcode('quote-system-processing', 'qt_system_processing');

function qt_system_processing() {
    $myuser = $_POST['username'];
    echo "The following was passed (".$myuser.")";
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you **do not** use [reserved names](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77337/page-returns-404-with-post-variables-but-not-without)?

Comment: might not be related but shortcodes should return text, not echo it.

Comment: The actual code that I used specified names such as continent, country & town and all of these were blank when I moved it to the new server.
With respect to the return comment can you please explain this further ?

Comment: [How shortcode callbacks should work](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/shortcode-outputs-at-the-top-of-the-content).

Comment: Thanks for this help. I just tried it with testvalue instead of username and got same result.
If I test the value of $myname with an if statement then it is definitely an empty string so not sure why the return comment is relevant.

Comment: does the same thing happen using the `get` method? ... (to answer the bit about return if you replace `echo` with `return` in the shortcode the output will appear where it should rather than when it is processed - which are not always the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

I have now tracked this down to the polylang plugin. When the plugin is active and '&lang=en' is added to the URL, the $_POST variables are lost. If I disable the plugin, all is well. Since I want translations, I may have to use a different plugin for that. Can anybody help?