# Mail Form in a modal box without plugin

Tags: forms

I've builded a WordPress theme based on Twitter Bootstrap 3.x. I've a mail form in modal box. When I click submit button, it returns 404 error page. I also checked [for **reserved names**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77337/385) in `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` variables.

What can be the reason?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<?php
$hasError = '';
$succMsg = '';
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$bsvr_ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
$bsvr_ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):

    $secret = 'key';
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    if (!empty($_POST['bsvr_name'])) {
        $bsvr_name = stripslashes(trim($_POST['bsvr_name']));
    } else {
        $hasError = "Lütfen adınızı giriniz.";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['bsvr_email'])) {
        $bsvr_email = stripslashes(trim($_POST['bsvr_email']));
    } else if ( ! eregi( "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['bsvr_email'] ) ) ) {
        $hasError = 'Geçersiz e-posta adresi girdiniz.';
    } else {
        $hasError = "Lütfen e-posta adresinizi giriniz.";
    }

    $bsvr_egitim = $_POST['bsvr_egitim'];

    if($responseData->success):

        $to = 'tomail';
        $subject = 'Title';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <p><b>Name: </b>".$bsvr_name."</p>
            <p><b>E-Mail: </b>".$bsvr_email."</p>
            <p><b>Title: </b>".$bsvr_egitim."</p><br/><br/>
            <p><b>IP: </b>".$bsvr_ip_address."</p>
        ";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:'.$bsvr_name.' <'.$bsvr_email.'>' . "\r\n";

        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

        $succMsg = "Ok..";
        $bsvr_name = '';
        $bsvr_email = '';
        $bsvr_egitim = '';

    else :

        $hasError = "Bir hata oluştu, lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.";

    endif;

else :

    $hasError = "Bir hata oluştu, lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.";

endif;
else :

$hasError = '';
$succMsg = '';
$bsvr_name = '';
$bsvr_email = '';
$bsvr_egitim = '';  
endif;
?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="basvuru" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EĞİTİME BAŞVUR</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="contactForm" id="egitimform" name="egitimform" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bsvr_name" id="bsvr_name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="bsvr_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="bsvr_email" class="form-control" name="bsvr_email" id="bsvr_email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="bsvr_egitim" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="egitimsubmit" value="GÖNDER">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#egitimsubmit').on('click', function(e){
// We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
e.preventDefault();

// Find form and submit it
$('#egitimform').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving the `action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"` empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only changed `<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">` to `<div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">`. And now it works.