# wordpress form action page not found

Tags: php, actions, forms, html, 404-error

I have created a page template with a form like this

```
<form id="form_52393" class="appnitro" action="../application.php" 
method="post">
<div class="form_description">
<h2>Finance Application Form</h2>
Enter the course name, its price, the term of you finance and your 
deposit. You will then be reidrected to an online application form to 
complete the process.

</div>
<ul>
    <li><label class="description" for="action">action</label>
<div><input id="element_9" class="element text medium" 
maxlength="255" name="action" type="hidden" 
value="credit_application_link" /></div></li>
    <li id="li_5"><label class="description" 
for="Identification[api_key]">Identification[api_key] </label>
<div><input id="element_5" class="element text medium" 
maxlength="255" name="Identification[api_key]" type="hidden" 
value="be803c55eeaf79c89b6ff46ac6a9a039" /></div></li>
<li id="li_6"><label class="description" 
for="Identification[InstallationID]">Identification[InstallationID] 
</label>
<div><input id="element_6" class="element text medium" 
maxlength="255" name="Identification[InstallationID]" type="hidden" 
value="13161" /></div></li>
    <li><label class="description" 
 for="Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]">
Identification[RetailerUniqueRef] 
</label>
<div><input id="element_7" class="element text medium" 
maxlength="255" name="Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]" 
type="hidden" value="test999" /></div></li>
<li id="li_1"><label class="description" 
for="Goods[Description]">Course Name </label>
<div><input id="element_1" class="element text medium" 
maxlength="255" name="Goods[Description]" type="text" value="" />
</div></li>
    <li id="li_10"><label class="description" 
for="Goods[Price]">Price </label>
<span class="symbol">£</span><input id="element_12_1" class="element 
text currency" name="Goods[Price]" size="10" type="text" value="" /> 
.
<label for="element_12_1">Pounds</label></li>
    <li id="li_4"><label class="description" 
for="Finance[Code]">Finance Type </label>
<div><select id="element_4" class="element select medium" 
name="Finance[Code]">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="ONIF6">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 6 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF9">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 9 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF10">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 10 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF12">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 12 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF18">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 18 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF24">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 24 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIF36">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 36 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB12-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 12 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB18-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 18 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB24-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 24 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB36-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 36 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB12-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 12 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB18-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 18 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB24-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 24 month 
term</option>
<option value="ONIB36-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 36 month 
term</option>
</select></div></li>
    <li id="li_12"><label class="description" 
for="Finance[Deposit]">Price </label>
<span class="symbol">£</span><input id="element_12_1" class="element 
text currency" name="Finance[Deposit]" size="10" type="text" value="" 
/> .
<label for="element_12_1">Pounds</label></li>
    <li class="buttons"><input name="form_id" type="hidden" 
value="52393" /><input id="saveForm" class="button_text" 
name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Which on submit should post data and trigger this php script

```
<?php
$interface = "https://test.dekopay.com:3343/";
    $postFields = Array(
    "action" => "credit_application_link",
    "Identification[api_key]" => "be803c55eeaf79c89b6ff46ac6a9a039",
    "Identification[InstallationID]" => "13161",
    "Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]" => uniqid(),
    "Goods[Description]" => "",
    "Goods[Price]" => "",
    "Finance[Code]" => "",
    "Finance[Deposit]" => "",
);

function httpPost($interface, $postFields)
{
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $interface);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    return $curl_response = curl_exec($curlSession);
}
header('Location: ' . httpPost($interface, $postFields),True);
exit();
?>
```

Which should check the submitted data then redirect to a third party generated url.

Instead I am receiving either "page not found" or a plain white page. THe template file and php file are in the same child theme folder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does your application.php really sit in the parent directory (from the client's point of view)?

Comment: I assume you get your posted values further up the script? But as @janh2 has already stated - are you sure 'application.php' is two directories up from where the form is located? It looks as if application.php is located in the `wp-content` folder?

Comment: Currently, application.php and the form template sit in this directory /wp-content/themes/medipro-sub/

Comment: Then you should let your form action reflect that: `action="/wp-content/themes/medipro-sub/application.php"`. Does it work with that change?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean action="/wp-content/themes/medipro-sub/deko_app.php" as that's the php file which should be triggered? When I change that I get a plain white page with the following in the address bar
"http://example.co.uk/wp-content/themes/medipro-sub/deko_app.php"

Comment: You are using [reserved names](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77339/73) in your form. Try changing that.

Comment: Is there a way around this? I believe the "action" field is what might be causing the issue but unfortunately I cannot prefix this as it relates to a third party companies parameters. So the field needs to be submitted with the name "action"

Comment: The `action` field in your code is pointing to a relative URL. This must fail. Use an absolute URL instead.